# Should I add cursor pointer to <body> tag on any touch device

Tags: css

I see very large websites such as Facebook have a css

```
body.touch {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What is the value in adding cursor pointer for a touch device? I understand its use for desktop (show a pointer sign for the mouse) but not on touch devices?

For me most are mobile but maybe this targets touch device that are not mobile phones such as touch laptops?

Comment: `.touch` is a css class for when the finger is pressed on the screen, to give the impression the browser is responding from your fingertip.

Comment: i don't understand: what impression do you mean? i mean i don't see any pointer on my iphone...? Visually, what's this "impression" ?

Comment: you're making quite the impression:) Yeah i know the english word. I am asking : you say "to give the impression the browser is responding from your fingertip" but in practice how does the browser gives the impression it's responding to my finger tip when I use cursor:pointer on MOBILE. (i know on desktop of course)

Comment: Under your finger, will be the impression. Maybe you have fat fingers :)